I have an error in posting my categories to database
I am writing a project in ASP.NET Core, and while using the Razor page architecture, I can add a product in the add page, but the problem arises when I decide to add categories in the add page, in displaying the categories is not a problem, but the main problem is when I want to send the categories to the database
My AddEditProductVM:
using DataLayer.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer.ViewModel
{
    public class AddEditProductVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="نام")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="توصیف")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="قیمت")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="موجودی")]
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="تصویر")]
        public IFormFile Picture { get; set; }

        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}

My add.cshtml view:
@page
@model StoreCoreIrib.Pages.Admin.AddModel
@{
}

<h3>صفحه افزودن کالا</h3>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dd>
            <label asp-for="Product.Name"></label>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name"></span>
        </dt>
        
        <dd>
            <label asp-for="Product.Description"></label>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Description"></span>
        </dt>
        
        <dd>
            <label asp-for="Product.Price"></label>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input asp-for="Product.Price" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Price"></span>
        </dt>
        
        <dd>
            <label asp-for="Product.QuantityInStock"></label>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input asp-for="Product.QuantityInStock" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Product.QuantityInStock"></span>
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <label asp-for="Product.Picture"></label>
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input asp-for="Product.Picture" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Picture"></span>
        </dt>

         @* <dd>
            لیست گروه های محصول
        </dd>
            <dt>
            @foreach(var item in Model.Product.Categories)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedGroups" value="@item.Id" /> @item.Name <br>
            } 
            
        </dt> 

        <dd>
            
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="ثبت محصول" />
        </dt>
    </dl>
</form>

My Add.cshtml.cs code behind file:
using DataLayer;
using DataLayer.Entity;
using DataLayer.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace StoreCoreIrib.Pages.Admin
{
    public class AddModel : PageModel
    {
        private StoreContext _db;

        public AddModel(StoreContext context)
        {
            _db = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public AddEditProductVM Product { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<int> SelectedGroups { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Product = new AddEditProductVM()
            {
                Categories = _db.Categories.ToList(),
            };
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return Page();

            var item = new Item()
            {
                Price = Product.Price,
                QuantityInStock = Product.QuantityInStock
            };

            _db.Add(item);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            var pro = new Product()
            {
                Name = Product.Name,
                Item = item,
                Description = Product.Description,
            };

            _db.Add(pro);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            if (Product.Picture?.Length > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                    "wwwroot", "Images", pro.Id + Path.GetExtension(Product.Picture.FileName));

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Product.Picture.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }

            if (SelectedGroups.Any() && SelectedGroups.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (int gr in SelectedGroups)
                {
                    _db.CategoryToProducts.Add(new CategoryToProduct()
                    {
                        CategoryId = gr,
                        ProductId = pro.Id
                    });
                }
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
}

I wanted to post my categories when I select to my database, but I get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Pages_Admin_Add.b__14_0() in Add.cshtml, line 71


What's on line 71? What do you get while debugging?

@foreach(var item in Model.Product.Categories) this is line 71 in Add.cshtml and program says here object reference not set to an instance of an object , do you know why?

har you tried debugging and set a breakpoint to see what data is null? the error is usually a result of not providing the correct data

yes I did, in my Add.cshtml.cs in OnGet categories get data but product is null, I really don't know why, I tried everything but I couldn't solve it, the matter is I did like this before in visual studio 2019 and .net5 and I didn't have any problem but in visual studio 2022 and .net8 I came across  this problem

I solved this question, it was enough to make the properties nullable in the model to solve this problem. In fact, the problem was solved only by placing a question mark
